# Change matplotlib style in pyqt5

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt5

In my PyQt5 application there is a widget which contains graph built with matplotlib. The graph looks old-fashioned and I want something modern. I have to use FigureCanvasQTAgg. Now, I do not know how to change style of the graph. My code:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=5, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.plot()


    def plot(self):
        x = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.21)
        ran_floats = np.random.rand(10) * (7.3 - 0.5) + 0.5
        y = (1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * ran_floats))
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(x, y)
        ax.set_title("text")
        ax.grid()
```

Comment: It's not clear what "old-fashioned" means and how you would like it to look instead. Matplotlib has [several build-in styles](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/style_sheets/style_sheets_reference.html) and you can [create your own style](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) if needed. Did you try anything?

Comment: I mean, I would like to have any style different from default one. The problem is that I have no clue how to change it in the code above.

Comment: That's unfortunate. If you can tell at which part the [guide](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) needs more information, we could sure add that.

Comment: As can be easily seen the guide suggest to use `plt.style.use('presentation')`. However, it does not work, and was not supposed to help in this case.

Comment: 'presentation' is used as an placeholder for a custom style. `matplotlib.style.available` returns a list of currently available styles.

Comment: I've tried "fast". Didn't work out.

Comment: It does work. Except that the only difference between the default and `"fast"` is not so much a visual one, but concerns the rendering time. I linked you to the example with all build-in styles. Choose one which you find appealing.

Answer (score 0):

you can start with one of matplotlib built-in stylesheetes; it can be a little intimidating at first, but i used a trial & error approach to acheive what i wanted.
refer to this for existing builtin stylesheets: [matplotlib Style sheets reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/style_sheets/style_sheets_reference.html), and refer to this [The default matplotlibrc file](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/customizing.html#customizing-with-style-sheets) on what/how to change. once done, you need to place your cutom file in the same directory where Matplotlib stores its mplstyle files: `.../Lib/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib` then set stylesheet in your code using the cutom mplstyle file name without its extension: `plt.style.use('mystyle')`